# A question about the Collatz sequence

Tags: number-theory, collatz-conjecture

Let be N the integer from which you start the Collatz sequence.

And let be Mx(N) the maximum reached starting from N.

Skipping trivial trajectories, are there infinitely many N such that:

$N\equiv 3^j\pmod {42}$ and
$Mx(N) \equiv 2^k\pmod {42}$, for some positive k and j?

N=993 and Mx(993)=8080 are an example.

Infact 993 $\equiv 27\pmod {42}$ and 8080 $\equiv 16\pmod {42}$

N=27 and Mx(27)=9232 are a non example because 9232 is not congruent to $2^k\pmod {42}$

Is N=993 and Mx(993) the least example? Or are there N's<993 with such property?

Comment: Are there any non-examples?

Comment: N=27 and Mx(27)=9232 should be a non example

Comment: N=1819 Mx(N) =1276936 is another non example, ok?

Comment: @Arthur I think that there are a lot of non examples

Comment: You're right. I initially thought they would be fewer and further between, but I had a mistake in my thought process. At the very least I can say this: any odd multiple of $3$ is a power of $3$ modulo $42$. So that's many candidate $N$'s. And a "random" even number has probability $\frac12$ of being a power of $2$ modulo $42$, as Collatz numbers are never multiples of $3$ after the first $3n+1$ step. So I'd _expect_ there to be many examples. But it is always difficult to tell with Collatz.

Comment: @Arthur unfortunately I have not a program to test it

Comment: There is no program to test this. No program can directly count whether there are infinitely many of anything.

Comment: @Arthur you just want an example with $N<993$ and a specific property, so you can definitively write a program to check it

Comment: @Peter N=993 has the maximum residue known, is it also the least number N with the above property?

Comment: @Arthur why is any odd multiple of 3 a power of 3 mod 42? $3^7\equiv 3\mod 42$ and same with $2$. Perhaps you thought $42$ is a prime number?

Comment: @GarethMa $3=3^1$, $9=3^2$, $15=3^6$, $27=3^3$, $33=3^5$, $39=3^4$. However, $21$ isn't a power of $3$ because it's divisible by $7$. So I missed that one.

Comment: And I misread the question, somehow thinking it was asking whether there are infinitely many of these, not what the smallest one is. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

$N=3$ and $Mx(3)=16$ satisfy your requirements. For more example check this code [here](https://tio.run/##bZDRasIwFIavm6f4QQatnmFzUp0KhT3A6AuMbUhNtcwmJW1B9/Ld6aZX211y@M@X/0t77U/emcf22l7HcQbzXqPuUHp3DIN1PXoPTYa2xE9ktmQM6RUaf0DGagb@N86U0Yb0mgwT8z2tquAbVIMre@/PHeqm9aHHXD2fw/BR7suTjZv9pau/bF54ZxN1sBWaS@ySnYrqCi7P9S7YfggOWkW3k6zEjqbYcsmYYngAI8@Rwp47CzN3C50kSuq@eN/uVOUDPlE7hL072linaTq9MI3DNH7VBEPYEsQZIg2xhl69SSgqkEtqIUKYC2WG4s8HhLtxNLWWZkUilWThxmZCRtgIci1ouTH/oKM21EKIC/pdSsaRVYY1tFEMI87f)